# How to connect to windows server 2012 from windows 8.1

Tags: azure, client, server, connect

I am completely new to this challenge. The scenario is :

I have create two virtual machines on Microsoft Azure. First VM is Windows Server 2012 R2 and second VM is Windows 8.1

I have configured a domain controller on Windows Server. I want to connect to server from windows 8.1

I have attempted following:
In the browser of windows 8.1 - http://dc/connect

but it shows error as:

`This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://dc is correct. 
•Look for the page with your search engine. 
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.`

Also I tried changing domain of windows 8.1 machine. but it is not allowing me

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing preventing you from connecting to a Windows Server machine from Windows 8.1 in Azure. What probably you did wrong is the network configuration. Both VMs must be in the same virtual network. When you create a new VM, you have to choose "From Gallery" to be able to select the VNet you will deploy it to. Once both machines are in the same VNet you will be able to ping the private address, join domain, access network file shares, etc.

Deploy using "Quick Create" only if you want to quick test something solo. At this point, if you really didn't setup the network configuration properly you will have to redeploy. Just delete the Windows 8 VM (without deleting the VHD) and after a while the machine disk should appear on the vm creation wizard under "My disks". Just recreate the VM using the original settings and making sure the VNet for both VMs are the same.

**Virtual Network Overview**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156007.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do remote desktop connection ,in your search tab type remote desktop connection and set your domain and user name. than connect it.